# How to configure Okhttp to use several instances using http2

Tags: spring-boot, okhttp, http2

I have a question regarding Okhttp library and I'm hoping somebody could help out. I have two microservices. Microservice A call microservice B. Both are using http2. Microservice B has several instances and is behind a loadbalancer. What I'm seeing is that all the request go to one instance. This is the instance the first request from microservice A was send to. What I would like to see is the load to be spread evenly to the instances of microservice B. Below my Okhttpclient setup:

```
        @Bean
    public OkHttpClient okHttpClient(AiProperties aiProperties) {

        HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        Dispatcher dispatcher = new Dispatcher(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(600));
        dispatcher.setMaxRequests(600);
        dispatcher.setMaxRequestsPerHost(1);

        return new OkHttpClient.Builder().connectionPool(new ConnectionPool(600, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES))
                .dispatcher(dispatcher)
                .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
                .protocols(Collections.singletonList(Protocol.H2_PRIOR_KNOWLEDGE))
                .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
                .dns(new Dns() {
                    @NotNull
                    @Override
                    public List<InetAddress> lookup(@NotNull String s) throws UnknownHostException {
                        InetAddress ip1 = Inet4Address.getByName("dns-url");
                        return Arrays.asList(ip1);
                    }
                })
                .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
                .build();
    }
```

```
            req = new Request.Builder().url(aiProperties.getBaseUrl() + aiProperties.apiurl())
                .addHeader(aiProperties.getApiKeyHeaderName(), aiProperties.getApiKey())
                .addHeader("Connection", "close")
                .put(requestBody)
                .build();

        CompletableFuture<Boolean> f = new CompletableFuture<>();

        okHttpClient.newCall(req).enqueue(new Callback() {
```

On the tomcat webserver a connector:

```
    @Bean
public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> tomcatCustomizer() {
    return (factory -> {
        if (factory.getWebServer() instanceof TomcatServletWebServerFactory) {
            TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = (TomcatServletWebServerFactory) factory.getWebServer();
            tomcat.addConnectorCustomizers(connector -> {
                if (connector.getProtocolHandler() instanceof Http2Protocol) {
                    Http2Protocol protocolHandler = (Http2Protocol) connector.getProtocolHandler();
                    protocolHandler.setMaxConcurrentStreams(1);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}enter code here
```

What I'm I doing wrong?

Kind regards,

J

I tried several configurations from very low values to removing the dispatcher but always he same result. I'm expecting the requests to be evenly devided between the instances of microservice B

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to hijack a question specific to `OkHttp`, but wanted to let know that Jetty's `HttpClient` can be configured with a round-robin (or random) strategy so that it would possible to distribute the HTTP/2 load across backend servers.

I'll gladly share more details in a different question.

Answer (score 0):

OkHttp has connection affinity and will reuse a connection whenever it can. You can achieve more balance by configuring the maximum streams per connection. This should be configurable somewhere on the HTTP/2 server. OkHttp will honor this setting.

Comment: Hi Jesse, Thank you for your reply. I don't see you this will help dividing the load between the instances. My understanding of Okhttp works is it will reuse a connection. So if 4 connections were made to instance B 3 will be closed and one will be used (coalescing). Can you clarify a bit more?

Comment: On each HTTP/2 server you can configure how many concurrent streams (ie. HTTP calls) can be carried by each TCP connection. When the client connects, it won’t open a 2nd TCP connection until this limit is exceeded. Set the limit to what you want to achieve better balance.

Comment: Hi Jesse, I've tried your suggestion. I've modified the code sample to show you how it is currently configured. Unfortunately al the requests go to one service instead of being devided between the two if an instance of service A already has a connection to an instance to service B. I'm seeing a stream refused error so I've added a dns lookup. I've read if I connection fails Okhttp will retry the request on another instance. I'm not sure if a stream refused error is among the errors which triggers the retry reqeust. If you have any futhers suggestions? Thanks Josip